# What does the padlock on wifi icon in status bar mean?

Tags: wi-fi, notification-icons

What does the Padlock on the WiFi icon in the status bar mean? I haven't seen it on my phone, but I'm curious as to what it means.

[image: Screenshot showing padlock on WiFi icon]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

Comment: What device is that? I guess it's a secured wifi network (padlocks always mean secure)

Comment: Yeah but since when is this icon in status bar instead of just usual wifi icon?

Comment: Since android is 100% customisable, this may be a custom icon for this manufacturer. What device is this?

Comment: Looks like a Mediatek device

Comment: @esQmo it's LG K10 2017 edition I don't know exact model name, but since is Russian here it could be mediatek device, how do you know that?

Comment: Because of the modem version name: MOLY.LR11.W1552....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means, it is a [secure WiFi network](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/nexus/FxoU2i5i8QM/jPT9VPz5VS8J), the device is connected to

Edit: See [Wi-Fi lock](https://material.io/icons) symbol here

Comment: For me it's hard to believe because nowhere there is actual picture of icon. I will be very thankful if you can provide some link with it.

Comment: Linked to material icon symbol page

Comment: I saw the icon but no explanation, that is what I search for icon and explanation on same place. Thanks however.

Comment: I too couldn't find both in same place. Will update of I find. Thanks for accepting